# Some advice that I "hope" the heads of the community could consider

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes, scope

Hope you guys could take a minute and think about it.

In my opinion, this community is "**WAY TOO HARSH**"!!!

1. You guys put **TOO MUCH** emphasize on `Do your research first before you post a question`, but haven't it ever occur to you guys that

   > **People may NOT have the time and leisure to spend hours and hours of time digging through every links in Google and read through all the documents!? Not to mention "understand" it!?**

   I never say that one should never "do his homework". But please don't be too hard on them!
2. The "reason" of the down-votes should be added.

   I mean, after all, if you want somebody to improve his/her question, shouldn't you tell him/her "**WHAT TO IMPROVE**"!?

   So, if I could suggest,

   > In the future, when people down-voting, force him/her to put down the "reason" for down-voting!

   It could still be anonymous, but the "reason" **`MUST`** be put down!
3. Advocate to the members to be "nicer" to the "lesser educated".

   I mean, think about it, if one is lesser educated, the ability to post an "intelligent question" is therefore lower!

   Showing some niceties will encouraging and help him/her grow faster.

   After all, this site is for "helping people", not "condemn" him for not being as smart and well-educated as you.

That's it so far, hope you guys could take some time and consider it!

Comment: As to the part of #3 that's '"condemn" him for not being as smart and well-educated as you': If someone is saying something that is condemning another user for being less well-educated, that is likely to be against the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). In such case, you should flag whatever it was for moderator attention. Flags can be raised on questions, answers, and comments. Under most conditions this requires a minimum of [15 reputation](/help/privileges/flag-posts), but you can flag comments on your own posts regardless of reputation. [more info](/a/313203)

Comment: _"People may NOT have the time and leisure to spend hours and hours of time digging through every links in Google and read through all the documents!? Not to mention "understand" it!?"_ It seems to me you've forgotten that people helping here are volunteering their free time, not doing everything you can to make it as easy as possible to help you seems rude to me.

Comment: **[Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437/839601)**

Comment: One of the reasons SO is so harsh on question askers is because they are valued less than question answerers. You allow askers to be lax and write lazy questions folks won't want to, or not even be able to, answer them. Without answerers, the site is useless.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's fine to not actually be a genius.

But at the end of the day you're expecting people to spend their time solving your problems and a minimal investment in time on your end is nice.

I've also had situations where I was stuck with a problem for an extended of time, googled and found a perfectly clear answer on SE. Someone did the research, and solved my problem in about 10 minutes, and I ended up not even needing to ask (I did upvote and give a *huge* bounty for making my day).

No one starts off knowing everything - least of what what a random stranger on the internet knows. By showing what you have tried we can skip those things and focus on new ideas. Showing your work saves everyone time

Spending time with Google, research and self directed problem solving is how folks 'get smarter' so by making the effort you become smarter and better educated.

As such it feels fair for someone asking a question to respect the time and effort of folks posting answers.

> People may NOT have the time and leisure to spend hours and hours of time digging through every links in Google and read through all the documents!? Not to mention "understand" it!?

... Is precisely why you find value here. Someone did that. They've synthesised that knowledge into something you would find useful. Its nice for folks to share knowledge and respect each other - rather than expecting folks to spend the time you're saying you're unwilling to spend.